# I need alternating X and O when I click UI buttons in MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab, if-statement, tic-tac-toe

I am making a tic tac toe game and can't figure out the correct order to get alternating buttons. This is the callback for my pushbutton uicontrol

```html
function ex_ttt_update2( handle, event )
persistent var

if (var=='X')
    var='O';
elseif (var=='X')
    var='X';
else
    var='X';

    
set (handle,'string',var)    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First decide on the case you are using. In first `if` you are comparing against the lowercase `x`, while elsewhere you are assigning uppercase ones. Second the lines:

```
elseif (var=='X')
    var='X';
```

Are setting `var` to be `X` if it is already `X`. I.e. doing nothing. You might want to change it to

```
elseif (var=='O')
    var='X';
```

And it is pretty useless given you are assigning `X` anyway in the last `else`. So maybe the last else should clear the cell instead.

Comment: Yea that was a mistype for x. This is just a template, i mixed up the O's and X's and accidentally saved. I needed it to do nothing because I cant have someone say replace an X with an O but I have other ideas on that. Such as disabling the button after, but for now i just need it alternating.